# phpmyadmin automaticaly select the database user will use

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a user named `dbUser` that only has access to one database `myDatabase` and was wondering if it's possible to have that db automatically selected when the user logs in and phpMyAdmin is started, rather then having to select it from the the list on the left hand side where its the only one listed.

Comment: Try this:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = 'myDatabase';

https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_only_db

Comment: Thanks for the replay and wouldn't that set 'myDatabase' as the default db for all of the users?  i was just trying to set the default database for just 'dbUser'.  Maybe that is not possible.   Oh well, just thought I'd ask and see if it was possible and how to do it.

Comment: Indeed that would set the default db for all of the users. It's possible to do it per user, with "phpMyAdmin configuration storage" enabled. When enabled, log in with dbUser then go to Settings > Features > Databases > Show only listed databases,